# KO theory v.s. ko theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory, topological-k-theory, cobordism

It looks that there are different types of topological K-theories, with similar names but they are totally different outputs for the same input.

The first theory is called the [KO theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KO-theory). There are very limited information I can find on nlab.

The second theory is called the [ko theory](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/169/surv169-endmatter.pdf). Say the [ko-Homology studied in Chapter 10 of this book](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/169/surv169-endmatter.pdf).

My question is that is there a simple way to contrast the twos:

KO theory v.s. ko theory?

For example, we can compare:

- $KO_d(BG)_p$
- $ko_d(BG)_p$

with the spin bordism group:

- $\Omega_d^{Spin}(BG)_p$

Here we use the subindex to denote the $p$-torsion part (mean $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for some $n$). We can focus on $p=2$ and free part, for $d\le 7$; since there is [a theorem given here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312050/27004), saying that
$$ko_d(BG)_2=\Omega_d^{Spin}(BG)_2.$$

Comment: Maybe this will help: $KO$ is a 8-periodic spectrum, and $ko$ is its connective cover.